# An array element keep stacking at 1st position of an Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a little problem with my flash game. My array of birds (obstacles) everytime when they reach let's say x -800 they respawn at the starting position in everytime at random place in an array and it works well.
BUT
Every time it loops, birds 1 by 1 stacks at the first position of an array. It is weird.

```
 public function setUpBirds() {
            for (var i:int = 0 ;i< 10; i++) {
            var mcClip:Bird = new Bird();
            var yVal:Number = (Math.ceil(Math.random()*100));
            birds.push(mcClip);
            birds[i].x = 100 * i;
            birds[i].y = yVal * i;

            birdsContainer.addChild(mcClip);

        }
        }

private function moveBirds(event:Event):void {
            birdsContainer.x = birdsContainer.x -10;

            if (birdsContainer.x == -500) {
                birdsContainer.x = 500;

                setUpBirds();

                    }    

                }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: here this is what happens :     [link](https://youtu.be/T9YKsfwW65k)

Comment: Did you get it figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime your `birdsContainer` has an `x` of `500`, you call `setUpBirds()`,  so let's step though and look at what's happening:  (explained with code comments injected into your code)

First time `setUpBirds` runs:

```
    for (var i:int = 0 ;i< 10; i++) {

        //a new bird is created 10 times
        var mcClip:Bird = new Bird();
        var yVal:Number = (Math.ceil(Math.random()*100));

        //you add it to the array
        birds.push(mcClip);

        //birds[1] properly refers to the item you just pushed into the array
        birds[i].x = 100 * i;
        birds[i].y = yVal * i;

        birdsContainer.addChild(mcClip);

    }
```

First time through, everything is great, your `birds` array has 10 items in it now.

Now, second time the function runs:

```
    for (var i:int = 0 ;i< 10; i++) {
        //create 10 more new birds (in addition to the last ones)
        var mcClip:Bird = new Bird();
        var yVal:Number = (Math.ceil(Math.random()*100));

        //add to the array (which already has 10 items in it)
        birds.push(mcClip); //so if i is 5, the item you just pushed is at birds[14]

        //birds[i] will refer to a bird you created the first time through
        //eg bird[0] - bird[9] depending on `i`, but really you want bird[10] = bird[19] this time around
        birds[i].x = 100 * i;  //your moving the wrong bird
        birds[i].y = yVal * i;

        //the new birds you create, will have an x/y of 0
        //since birds[i] doesn't refer to these new birds

        birdsContainer.addChild(mcClip);
    }
```

Now you see the problem?   your `birds` array now has 20 items in it,  so you are now referencing the wrong item in the array.

To fix this, just set the x/y on the `mcClip` var instead of the array,  or do `birds[birds.length-1].x = 100 * i` to use the last item added to the array.

On a side note, your performance is going to get pretty bad pretty fast creating 10 new birds all the time.  You need to get rid of those old birds if you're constantly creating new ones.

Seems like what you probably WANT to do is just reposition the existing birds every loop, so that would look something like this:

```
    for (var i:int = 0 ;i< 10; i++) {

        //check if there is NOT a bird already at this position in the array
        if(birds.length <= i || !birds[i]){
            //no bird yet, so create it and add it and push it
            var mcClip:Bird = new Bird();
            birds.push(mcClip);            
            birdsContainer.addChild(mcClip);
        }

        //now set the position of the bird
        var yVal:Number = (Math.ceil(Math.random()*100));
        birds[i].x = 100 * i;
        birds[i].y = yVal * i;
    }
```

This way, you only ever creating 10 birds and you are just resetting the `y` position of those birds every loop.